# display multi-line python console ascii animation

Tags: python

I'm playing with console animations. I see it's easy to make a single line but I started playing with the idea of animating GIFs as ASCII in the console.

```py
import time

def main():

    counter = 0

    while True:
        with open(ascii_path + 'dog-' + str(counter) + '.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:

            print('\b', f.read(), sep='', end='', flush=True)

            time.sleep(0.5)

            if counter == len(filenames):
                counter = 0
            else:
                counter += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What ends up happening is it will just print every text file in succession instead of replacing the contents like the following animation does.

```
for x in range(3):
    for frame in r'-\|/-\|/':
        # Back up one character then print our next frame in the animation
        print('\b', frame, sep='', end='', flush=True)
        sleep(0.2)
```

Even when I attempt to clear the console after every print, it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
os.system('cls')
```

Is there a library that does this?

Comment: could you provide a sample of the input file

Comment: @Abhi_J sure, updating now

Comment: I thought the question was pretty clear without the input files. Since they are pretty big I think you can best leave them out.

Comment: the code worked for me with `system('cls')`, so I just wanted to confirm if there was anything odd with the input file and also I meant a small portion of the file. Cheers!

Comment: Where are you running the script? Some environments are known for not allowing you to 'flush' printed out texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the problem with using `'\b'` is that it only clears a single character.

The following code with `system('cls')` function works for me on the cmd console of a windows system.
If you are on a mac or linux system use `system('clear')`

I tried with two sample files:

```
counter = 1
while True:
    with open('myfile{}.txt'.format(counter), 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
        print(f.read(), sep='', end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if counter == 2:
            counter = 1
        else:
            counter += 1
        system('cls')
```

Content of one file is printed then the screen is cleared and contents of the next file is printed.

Comment: Beautiful. That worked as expected. Your simplification of the file opening is elegant as well :)

Answer (score 2):

You can actually solve this without any external library as long as your terminal (emulator) supports [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). These can be printed to the console as if they are text but instead of printing they can move the cursor, change the colour of the text and even scroll portions of the terminal. Below is a small example that does what you want as long as the printed lines do not cause the terminal to scroll but if you are clearing the console anyway it should work.

```py
import time

nlines = 2
# scroll up to make room for output
print(f"\033[{nlines}S", end="")

# move cursor back up
print(f"\033[{nlines}A", end="")

# save current cursor position
print("\033[s", end="")

for t in range(10):
    # restore saved cursor position
    print("\033[u", end="")
    print(f"Line one @ {t}")
    print(f"Line two @ {t}")
    t += 1
    time.sleep(.5)
```

Comment: The console still scrolls with this solution

Comment: I have updated the code. It should now work as you want. `nlines` should be the number of lines (height) of your animation.